# Set css attributes for all non multiple select tags in internet explorer 8

Tags: html, css, select, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I want to set all non-multiple select tags that are not multiple to be italic, I want this not to be set to the multiple select tags. So far I've wrote this css:

```
select
{
    font-style:italic;  
}

select[multiple="multiple"]
{
    font-style:normal;
}
```

This works in any normal browser but does not work in internet explorer 8 (and 9, but that is less important). How can i get this to work in internet explorer 8?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS8sf/)

Comment: maybe it has to do with doctype and compat mode? what is you doctype ?

Comment: I haven't set any doctype, just like in theexample, should I have?

Comment: I just know that some people had issues related to doctype not declared. It impacts on IE compat mode (quirksmode or standard mode). But I have no idea if it would solve you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following at the very start of the HTML document:

```
<!doctype html>
```

This prevents IE from going to [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) where it does not recognize many CSS features, such as attribute selectors, among other things.

In addition, consider simplifying the selector to

```
select[multiple]
```

so that it will also apply to syntactic markup variants like `<select multiple>`.